# Why am I getting composer memory errors installing a 32 KB module?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-8

I’ve upgraded a website from Drupal 7 to Drupal 8
I did the configuration locally using ddev, using composer to install modules etc.

The site is now uploaded to our shared web host, which has a limit of 2 GB RAM.
I’m running into errors when I try and use composer to install new modules or perform upgrades

```
Composer require drupal/entity_delete
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 2147483648 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 4096 bytes) in phar:///opt/cpanel/composer/bin/composer/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/Solver.php on line 223
```

Our database is only 40 MB and file system is 400 MB and entity_delete is 32 KB so I'm trying to understand why Drupal needs over 2 GB of RAM and if there is a way to resolve this?
(without having to perform all the updates locally each time.)

Mark

Comment: Yeah Composer and Drupal 8 need a lot of memory. Anecdotally you want at least 2GB _free_ RAM (not total) to build D8 sites with Composer, but your dependencies must be more complicated I guess. It’ll get better with Composer 2, but for now your experience is a common one

Comment: do it locally and upload the vendor directory

Comment: Your database and public file system size, as well as the package size, are all irrelevant by the way - this is simply Composer running out of memory while trying to compute dependencies

Answer (score 0):

You need to increase the memory_limit to avoid this

Try `COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT=-1 composer require drupal/entity_delete` for a one shot run with no memory limit

See https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#memory-limit-errors for more explanations.

Comment: Please remember to include an explanation instead of just providing code or commands. Can you edit this answer to explain why this addresses the original question? It may also be useful to provide links to any relevant documentation for additional reading.

Comment: If the memory is limited by the host: telling the host it can use all available memory likely won't alleviate the problem.

Comment: It’s a known issue that I even encountered on a 16GB ram computer which was the dev environment. Increase the memory_limit or use all the memory available solve the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Drupal is fine, it is Composer -- If you can avoid doing `composer require` or `composer update` on the host and instead do that in a development environment; that would be the way to go. Then you take the updated composer.lock and simply run `composer install` on your host and that would be much less memory intensive.

Otherwise; I had a similar issue and ended up enabling swap memory so that I could do that on a host that only has 512MB of memory (Runs Drupal 9 fine).

How to do that would depend on your host operating system but look up on how to do that if you wish.